# What does the @ character do in the gnu C preprocessor

Tags: c

I encountered this line of code in the gnu C compiler for an STM8S MCU...

```
#define DEF_8BIT_REG_AT(NAME,ADDRESS) volatile unsigned char NAME @ADDRESS
```

This is defining a macro that defines internal registers in the CPU. However, I can't seem to find any description of the use of the @ character. I have seen the use of #@ together to place quotes around a character, but never the @ on it's own.
I'd appreciate if someone could explain the use of the @ character in this macro. Please don't comment if you are guessing....only if you know for sure. Also, I know what they are trying to do, so don't try to explain the basics of C preprocessing to me. I am a software engineer with over 30 years of experience. i.e. I'm just interested in the use of the @ character in the macro.
Please supply a link if possible.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is this code from?

Comment: From the ST tools downloadable from their site. It's the include file defining the CPU internal registers. Built using the mingw gcc compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of the preprocessor and has nothing to do with the preprocessor. It is an extension of the C compiler that lets you place symbols at particular memory locations. It is not standard C. In fact, I'm pretty sure it is *not* part of gcc (is that what you mean by the "gnu C compiler"?)  I've seen it used in other compilers, such as IAR or uVision.

For example see [this question](http://mcuoneclipse.com/2012/11/01/defining-variables-at-absolute-addresses-with-gcc/)

Comment: Thank you very much. That answers it for me. There are more portable ways to do this, but if it works.... Thanks again.